# Why can't my code run in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python

I can't run my code in Visual Studio Code. When I type `$ code hello.py` then this happens:

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hU8j.png)

Comment: Use `python hello.py` instead of  `code hello.py`. Please consider checking my answer for more information

Comment: Welcome To StackOverFlow, Click on the tick next to your favorite answer to mark it as your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the image you have used `code hello.py`. You should instead use `python hello.py`. You can run on the command prompt only if you had "Add Python  to Path" checked while installing the Python software.

**If you are on a Mac**

In Mac, Python 2.7 is automatically installed. If you want to use Python 3 then you have to manually install from the Python official website and use `python3 hello.py` to use Python 3.

Answer (score -1):

Always remember that a Python file will be run by using this command: `python yourfile_name.py`.

In your image you are trying to run your Python file with this command: `code hello.py`

Instead of using `code hello.py`, try to change it with `python hello.py`.

Comment: What does this answer add more to the answer posted 8 minutes before your answer?